# When creating Jenkins Windows build node, I get provided port is not reachable?

Tags: docker, jenkins

I'm running `jenkins/jenkins:lts` as a Docker container on a Ubuntu VM. I'm running interactive mode for now but will run it as a daemon later.

```
$ docker run --rm -p 8880:8080 -it --name jenkins -v /var/lib/jenkins:/var/jenkins_home jenkins/jenkins:lts
```

Now I'm trying to add build nodes, both Linux and Windows.

I added a Windows build node via the "Manage Nodes and Clouds" page. Once I've added the node, it tells me execute the following commands on the node, which I did

```
C:\> curl -sO http://my.jenkins.com:8080/jnlpJars/agent.jar
C:\> java -jar agent.jar -jnlpUrl http://my.jenkins.com:8080/computer/exa%2Dbuild%2D01/jenkins-agent.jnlp
```

Bot on the second command, I get following error that says

```
SEVERE: http://my.jenkins.com:8080/ provided port:39106 is not reachable
```

Where do I need to open the port, on the host or on container? Also, is there a range of ports? Thanks

Comment: You can try to enable the `Use WebSocket` in your node config page.

Comment: @C1sc0, thanks that worked! Put that as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

From @lamK's comment, clicking the `Use WebSocket` box in the build node configuration page did the trick.